# Ways to access Model's variables in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

Hi so I have a struct modal like following:

```
struct calmDocc: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {

var content: String
var id: String
var calmwordcount: Int
  }
```

I assign values to these inside some class (CalmManager) as follows

```
 let idcalm = something
                    let content = something as! String ?? ""
                    let calmwordcount = content.split { !$0.isLetter }.count
                    let calmDoccs = calmDocc(content:content, id:idcalm, calmwordcount: calmwordcount)

                    return (calmDoccs)
```

Now when I wish to call the `calmwordcount` var of CalmDoccs in some other view I have to use the following

```
ForEach(CalmManager.calmDoccs) { calmDoccs in
          
            Text(calmDoccs.calmwordcount.description)
        
        }
```

Is there some simple way to basically target one of the three variables I have defined inside calmDocc without using the ForEach command? Something like following "calmDoccs.content"? Would appreciate some help.

EDIT:

```
     self.calmDoccs = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> calmDocc in
                   let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                    let idcalm = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                    let content = data["content"] as! String ?? ""
                    let calmwordcount = content.split { !$0.isLetter }.count
                    let calmDoccs = calmDocc(content:content, id:idcalm, calmwordcount: calmwordcount)
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                    print(calmDoccs)
                    return (calmDoccs)
                }
```

EDIT 2: How I define class calmManager

```
class calmManager: ObservableObject {


@Published var calmDoccs: [calmDocc] = []
@Published var calmContent: String = ""
@Published var idcalm: String = ""
 //some code later down the line }
```

EDIT 3: This is what I get when I'm trynna add the word counts:

What I use:
`if CalmManager.calmDoccs.count > 0 && DarkManager.darkDoccs.count > 0{ Text("count: \(CalmManager.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount) + \(DarkManager.darkDoccs[0].darkwordcount)") }`

What I get: [image]

What I wish I would get:

count :10

Comment: show us the code you have for `class CalmManager`, including how you declare `calmDoccs`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine it's essentially data retrieved from firebase. I didn't add it to avoid confusion. But you can check my edits now. Does that help?

Comment: my comment/question was about how you **declare** `class CalmManager`. For example is it an `ObservableObject`, do you have `@Published var` in it. Also, how do you declare `calmDoccs`, is it a static var?, is it an array?

Comment: Yeah I do.  Just edited. My bad

Comment: please show a minimal sample code that shows what you want to do. At the moment, you just showing bits and pieces that do no make sense. Show us what error you get and explain what you want to achieve. Read also:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that may help you.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct CalmDocc: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var content: String
    var id: String
    var calmwordcount: Int
}

class CalmManager: ObservableObject {
    // for testing
    @Published var calmDoccs: [CalmDocc] = [
        CalmDocc(content: "content-1", id: "id-1", calmwordcount: 1),
        CalmDocc(content: "content-2", id: "id-2", calmwordcount: 2),
        CalmDocc(content: "content-3", id: "id-3", calmwordcount: 3)
    ]
    @Published var calmContent: String = ""
    @Published var idcalm: String = ""
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = CalmManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(manager.calmDoccs) { calmDocc in
                VStack {
                    Text(calmDocc.id)
                    Text(calmDocc.content)
                    Text("count: \(calmDocc.calmwordcount)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should read again the basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html and in particular, how to use an array, and collections in general:  (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html). I recommend you also do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

EDIT-1: to show only a specific element of `calmDoccs` array:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = CalmManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        if manager.calmDoccs.count > 0 {
            Text(manager.calmDoccs[0].id)
            Text(manager.calmDoccs[0].content)
            Text("count: \(manager.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount)")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-2: to get `totalCount` displayed.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject var manager1 = CalmManager()
    @StateObject var manager2 = CalmManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        if manager1.calmDoccs.count > 0 && manager2.calmDoccs.count > 0 {
            let totalCount = manager1.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount + manager2.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount
            Text("total count: \(totalCount)")

            // yes, you can also do this, pay attention to the details
            Text("total count: \(manager1.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount + manager2.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount)")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input sir. But this is the exact same approach I'm using. I'm trying to not use the For Each statement. I just wanna directly target the calmDocc values (without using the For each loop)

Comment: `manager.calmDoccs` is an array, and so you have to understand that you need to decide which element of the array you want to show. For example the first? the fifth? What? The `ForEach` will of course give you all the elements.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. I just wanna access calmwordcount. So how would the code change if we wanna access calmwordcount? Would we say 'third element'?

Comment: Oh just read your edit. Thanks for explaining. I see what you're doing. What if the array only has one element with those three variables? Cuz mine honestly only has one. So how would I access it then?

Comment: updated my answer. Note you still need to read and understand what an array is: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Hmm interesting. I think is see how this works. Thanks for the explanation. So what I'm technical trynna do is access the word count variable of calmDoccs and then add it to the word count variable of darkDoccs (another model with same properties). Does that make sense? The reason I can't use your second approach is that I can't really do something like Total Count =  calmmanager.calmDoccs[0].calmwordcount + darkmanager.darkDoccs[0].darkwordcount. That's what I wanted to accomplish but not able to do it still :/

Comment: Why can't you do `var totalCount = ...`? Show us the code you are trying to do and the error you get, Don't forget a **minimal reproducible code**.

Comment: Because I'm not sure how I'd define two managers in one if statement. Idk if I'm able to explain this well. Would you mind taking this to for chat for a few minutes?

Comment: I can show the code in the chat. If not I can update the question with the new code.

Comment: I don't do chat. Show the code you have, where it is not working, what error you get, and what you expect from your code. Update your question with your code.

Comment: Okay just updated.

Comment: updated my answer. As I said, you should do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/ without this you will not go very far coding a SwiftUI app.

Comment: Did my answer help resolve your problems? If so, could you mark it as accepted please, the tick mark turns green.